# survival analysis to understand time to completion in python

Tags: python, survival

We have a table where we have table that signifies the time T it takes for some data to arrive at destination table for a particular request.The table looks like below.How can I find the survival probablity for the events in this case?

```
Req Group 
    name   time to get data in seconds
1   A      626
2   A      635
3   B      656.27
4   D      682
5   A      986
6   C      2000
7   B      737
8   B      5000
9   D      717
10  C      800
11  C      704
12  A      736
13  D      712
14  D      696
15  D     1000
16  A     705
17  C     701
18  D     703
19  A     721
20  A     705
```

Comment: Is "name" relevant here? or do you simply care about "survival probability of arrival"?

Comment: Either way, you should look at lifelines: https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Survival%20analysis%20with%20lifelines.html (disclaimer: I'm the author)